# Is there an algebraic identity encoding the action of sums of 2 squares on non-sums of 2 squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I had asked a similar question earlier but it was flawed. Here is a corrected version. We can recall the [Sum of 2 squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) which states that if a natural number $n$ is a sum of two squares then in its prime factorization decomposition every prime factor $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$  has an even exponent.

The prime factorization decomposition of the sums of 2 squares makes it very easy to prove that the product of 2 sums of 2 squares is another sum of 2 squares.

But we also have the [Bhramagupta-Fibonacci Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity) $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2) = (ad+bc)^2 + (ac-bd)^2$ which shows us the same result.

I'm interested in generalizing this result. We know that every number that is NOT a sum of 2 squares should have some prime factor $3 \mod 4$ with an odd exponent.  It then follows that the product of a sum of 2 squares and a non sum of 2 squares should be again be a non sum of 2 squares.

I want to know if there is an algebraic identity to support that. Is there some algebraic function $P(x_1, x_2, ... x_n) $ such that its image over natural number tuples $(x_1, ... x_n)$ are the non sum of 2 square numbers and moreover that there exists an identity

$$ (a^2 + b^2)P(x_1, ... x_n) = P(Q_1, Q_2 ... Q_n)$$

Where the $Q_i$ are algebraic functions of $a,b,x_1, ... x_n$.

Comment: leaving out the wording, your suggestion is that two wrongs make a right. This is true as far as the Legendre symbol goes. However,  the numbers $3$ and $7$  are not the sums of two squares. But $21 = 3 \cdot 7$  is still not the sum of two squares. There is something like what you want when thre is more than one  binary form of the discriminant of interest.

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks for catching that typo. I have corrected it

Comment: @WillJagy yea I had noticed patterns like that and came up with some erroneous conjectures. I’ll have to understand quadratic forms better to see the ideas your last sentence was hinting at. If you have recommendations on resources I’d be grateful.

Comment: http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Cox-Primes_of_the_form_x2+ny2.pdf